# combining 2 tables, looping through the results and displaying items from each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, each

So I'm trying to combine two tables and show the results in order of the start_date.
I've tried a few things but because its technically a nested loop its giving me double results for each item.
The code i currently have is as follows

```
<% @subcategory = Subcategory.all %>
<% @product = Product.all %>
<% (@product + @subcategory).each do |product, subcategory|%>
<% if product.display_on_home_page and !product.is_highlight_product and !(product == '..') or subcategory.
display_on_home_page and !subcategory.is_highlight_product and !(subcategory == '..')%>
<div class="column_entry">
<%= link_to image_tag(subcategory.image_attachment.url(:normal_page_size)), subcategories_content_url(subcategory.id), :controller=>'subcategories' %>
</div>
<% end %>
<% if product.price_from %>
<div class="column_entry">
<div class="product_special">
    <span class="a">From Only</span>
    <span class="b"><%= number_to_currency(product.price,:unit=>'€') %></span>
</div>
<%= link_to image_tag(product.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(product.id), :controller=>'products' %>
</div>
<% else %>
<div class="column_entry">
<div class="product_special">
    <span class="a">Only</span>
    <span class="b"><%= number_to_currency(product.price,:unit=>'€') %></span>
</div>
<%= link_to image_tag(product.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(product.id), :controller=>'products' %>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

I know this is quite a long an complex statement, its supposed to loop through all of the subcategories and all of the products and display the images, there are also two different ways of displaying the price based on a boolean that says whether the price is a specific amount or it starts from a given price.

at the moment its reading through the loop but its giving me the error

```
 undefined method `is_highlight_product' for nil:NilClass
```

since this is the first column in the table that is referenced and its breaking here I think that there must be some conflict in its ability to see the information stored in the table.

I'm still quite new to ruby on rails so any help or even just a nudge in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

If you would like more information just ask in the comments and I'll put it up as fast as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, when you do something like this:

```
(@product + @subcategory).each do |product, subcategory|
```

The local variable `product` will iterate firstly through products, then through subcategories, and the local variable `subcategory` will always be nil.

What you can do, a dirty way - check

```
if product.is_a?(Product)
  # do your things
elsif product.is_a?(Subcategory)
  # do other things
end
```

Comment: so to loop through both do i need to add them in a single variable like
`@product = Product.all`
`@subcategory = Subcategory.all`
`@combo = @subcategory + @product`
`(@combo).each do |product, subcategory|`
and then define if statements based on product.is_a?(Product) etc.
well i got the code to run but its only seeing the products, I still have some tweaking to do but your answer was very helpful, if it totally straitens out this problem i'll accept it shortly.

Comment: You will not be able to loop parallel through both of them (only if you would like to go into Threads, but that is a lot of pain), do your models have any connection, as in: Subcategory belongs_to Product, or something ?